# How can i display loading/processing message inside DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my application i am using [datatables.net](https://datatables.net)

```
var ticketHistoryDataTable = $('#ticketHistoryData').DataTable({ 
        paging: false,
        data: [],
        searching: false,
        columns: [
            { data: 'ticket_id'         ,   title: "Ticket Number" },
            { data: 'transactiondate'   ,   title: "Date"          } 
        ]
} );
```

I am adding data to the table following way:

```
    var result_data = [{
            ticket_id         : '' ,
            transactiondate   : '' 
    },{
            ticket_id         : '' ,
            transactiondate   : '' 
    }];

    ticketHistoryDataTable.clear().draw();
    ticketHistoryDataTable.rows.add(result_data).draw();
```

result_data itself comes from jquery ajax get call to server. Retrieving the information may take some time, during which i want to display loading-processing message from datatable. What is correct way of doing this?

Comment: the corect way will be to use datatables ajax not an external ajax

Comment: Yes i understand. In my case, if there is a javascript object that is returning the data. I can not make in this case ajax call from datatable but still need to display loading message.

Comment: then use the `beforeSend` ajax event to display a loding message and hide it in the `success` method

Comment: Yes i understand that. On beforeSend I wand to show loading/processing message from datatable itself. What is correct way of doing this?

Comment: depends on where you want to put the message

Comment: I would prefer to display it as a table row. I am not sure how to do it correctly. I am not even sure where else is it possible to place the message (I do not want to create my custom message. I want to display DataTable's  message itself).

Comment: use jquery to append a new row to the table and remove it when the success function is called

Comment: Dear @madalin ivascu I do not want to create my custom message. I want to display DataTable's message itself

Comment: what is the datatables' message,datatables doesn't have messages

Comment: Same message it shows when loading data from datatables ajax, not an external ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a loader in your html. Position should be same as the table. [How to add a loader in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

or 
Message container: `<div id="MessageContainer"></div>`
and
Apply some CSS styles for good look and feel.

```
     $('#ticketHistoryData')
        .on( 'draw.dt', function () {
            console.log( 'Loading' );
          //Here show the loader.
          // $("#MessageContainer").html("Your Message while loading");
        } )
        .on( 'init.dt', function () {
            console.log( 'Loaded' );
           //Here hide the loader.
            // $("#MessageContainer").html("Your Message while load Complete");
        } )
        .DataTable({ 
            paging: false,
            data: [],
            searching: false,
            columns: [
                { data: 'ticket_id'         ,   title: "Ticket Number" },
                { data: 'transactiondate'   ,   title: "Date"          } 
            ]
     });
```

For more go through  [Events of DataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/event/)

I think this might help you.

You might show message

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dom` option to show loading:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "dom": 'lrtip'
} );
```

"r" letter is related to show loading element.
For more information [refer to this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

Answer (score 2):

When loading data from an Ajax source, you can use the following two events to handle the "Loading..." and "Done" states.

... data table code ...

```
    }).on('preXhr.dt', function ( e, settings, data ) {

        $(".thealert").html("Loading");

    }).on( 'draw.dt', function () {

        $(".thealert").html("Done");

    });
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is way the to display loading message on jQuery DataTable:

```
$('#myTableId').DataTable({
        "language": {
            'loadingRecords': 'Processing...',
        },

  // 'processing': true,
.
.
})
```

On above code,  // 'processing': true, is commented out, if not there will be two loading messages.

You also can do this way:

```
$('#myTableId').DataTable({
            "language": {
                'loadingRecords': '&nbsp;',
                'processing': 'Loading...'
            },
```

You can also show the loading spinner:

```
$('#myTableId').DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "loadingRecords": "<span class='fa-stack fa-lg'>\n\
                            <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-stack-2x fa-fw'></i>\n\
                       </span>&emsp;Processing ..."
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple
it uses build in language keyword

```
oTable = $('#UserTable').DataTable({
         "processing": true, // for show progress bar,
         retrieve: true,
         "language": {
                    'processing': '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading..n.</span>'
         },
```