# DataTables - processing div won't show if there are too many records

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.15 in Server Side mode on a web application.

The application has approx 240,000 records in the database. I've changed the results per page options to be as follows (25, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000 per page) set to a default of 250 records:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    // Ajax call etc ...

    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "lengthMenu": [ 25, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000 ],
    "pageLength": 250, 
});
```

Because of the time taken to make the ajax request I want to show the "processing" message `"processing": true` . All this does is toggles the visibility of this `<div>`:

```
<div id="myTable_processing" class="dataTables_processing panel panel-default" style="display: none;">Processing...</div>
```

However there's a problem with the way this works. In the DataTables CSS file we have this:

```
div.dataTables_processing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -26px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

This will never work with large result sets (e.g. 500, 1000, 2500, 5000 records) because it's shown 50% from the top of the screen. If you have tables of thousands of records, it is way down the page and the user would never see it unless they happened to scroll down to the appropriate section - which would also differ depending on the number of records shown, and they wouldn't have time to do this.

To make sure this is the case I added some options to my `lengthMenu` such as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and it does indeed work if there's no vertical scroll bar in the browser - presumably because 50% from the top is still visibile?

Is there a better/different way to implement this?

I've tried a `position: fixed;` in the CSS but it doesn't make it any better.

Comment: Did you check this- https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25666/how-to-customize-the-processing-message and this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650954/how-can-i-display-loading-processing-message-inside-datatable

Comment: @SouvikGhosh The first link - I tried that CSS which basically just gives it a `position:fixed` and that didn't work. The second link is no use as I don't want to implement any custom ajax loader - I want to use the one that's provided with DataTables.

Comment: I think you have to calculate the 'top', 'left' (and other necessary parameters) dynamically, based on the amount of records rather than putting a fixed value. Or you might have to compromise somewhere on showing the message at the top.